# Как получить все записи из таблицы, если есть массив id

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть массив строк где хранятся `id` продуктов. Как я смогу сделать один запрос в таблицу `products`, чтобы получить все строки с данным `id`?

Comment: `$sql = 'SELECT something FROM table WHERE id IN ('.implode(',', $idArray).')';`

Answer (score 2):

Для таких целей используется предикат `IN`.

Пример:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTable] mt WHERE mt.Id IN ('1','2','5')
```

Comment: зачем метки изменил у вопроса? автор не зря метку php поставил))  и вообще нужно было чтоб он уточнял это всё.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так а разве тут есть где-то php?)

Comment: Я про вопрос) тут написал, чтоб вы уведомление получили

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я понял ) но в вопросе же тоже php вроде никаким боком не упоминалось же

Comment: да, поэтому стоило, наверное, в начале что-то уточнить, прежде чем метки менять)